# Which of these is a proper JSON keyed array?

Tags: arrays, json, syntax

I am trying to write code to work with a RESTful 3rd party API that defines an endpoint that listens for a "keyed array of widgets" in JSON form. If a single "widget" has a proper JSON form of:

```
"widget": {
    "fizz": "true",
    "buzz": "45",
    "foo": "Always"
}
```

Then I ask: which one of the following correctly represents a "keyed array of widgets" (the term *keyed array* is from the API documentation), **and why?!?** Or, if none of them are correct, what is a correct "keyed array of widgets"? Please note that all the examples are arrays that only contain 1 widget each; that's fine for the sake of this question.

```
#1
"widgets": {
    widget_1: {
        "fizz": "true",
        "buzz": "45",
        "foo": "Always"
    }
}


#2
"widgets":[
    {
        "fizz": "true",
        "buzz": "45",
        "foo": "Always"
    }
]


#3
"widgets": [
    widget_1: {
        "fizz": "true",
        "buzz": "45",
        "foo": "Always"
    }
]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call #1 a collection of widgets, #2 an array of anonymous widgets, and I guess #3 really looks like a "keyed array of widgets". As for the why, well it's an array (square brackets), where each widget is stored with a key.

Comment: Thanks @MiklosAubert (+1) Are any of them "invalid" JSON?

Comment: Oh actually, #3 needs to be like this to be valid : [ { "widget_1" : { "fizz" : "true", "buzz" : "45", "foo": "Always" } } ]. #2 is valid if you wrap it in curly braces, making it a JSON Object. #1 also needs curly braces, and double quotes around "widget_1". You can test your JSON here : http://jsonlint.com/